# Many to Many Relationships |Insert | Delete

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, many-to-many, relational-database

I started using Entity Framework (Using POCO Classes) for a MVC 3 C# project with Razor Views.

I am having trouble implimenting the Many to Many features with it

I am trying to Create a View that when a User is able to add phone numbers, emails, musictypes, flags, holds, ntoes, etc... through Many to Many relationships

i.e.) **Company ----> CompanyVenue <---- Venue**

I have managed to get EF storing the Venue and then being able to asign the Venue afterwards by selecting the Venue in a list and assigning to to the Company.

Is there a way to get The Venue to automatically store the relationship from the Company to the Venue with out having to select it though a list?

If that is not possible can anyone share a better way of Implimenting using EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by having this simple setup:

```
public Company
{
    public virtual ICollection<Venue> Venues { get; set; }
}

public Venue
{
    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

EF should be able to determine that you're declaring a many-to-many relation. I don't know if you're using EF 4.1 Code First or the model designer, but Code First should have enought with this to create the `CompanyVenue` table for you. And the model designer will define the "link" table for you as well as soon as you declare a many-to-many relation.

Note that the navigation properties are marked as `virtual`. This is necessary in the case of collections so that EF can make the proper updates in the related entities.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to manually do this in Code First. Firstly your POCO classes might look something like this:

```
public class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        Venues = new List<Venue>();
    }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Venue> Venues { get; set; }
}

public class Venue
{
    public int VenueID { get; set; }
    public string VenueName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

In your DbContext:

```
public IDbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
public IDbSet<Venue> Venues { get; set; }
```

Also in the DbContext class override the OnModelCreating method. This is how you map the many to many relationship between Company and Venue:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
        .HasMany(comp => comp.Venues)
        .WithMany(venue => venue.Companies)
        .Map(mc =>
        {
        mc.ToTable("T_Company_Venue");
        mc.MapLeftKey("CompanyID");
        mc.MapRightKey("VenueID");
        }
    );

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

I answered another EF many to many question with full sample code here:

[MVC many to many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531769/saving-many-to-many-relationship-data-on-mvc-create-view/11593957#11593957)

I also wrote the above into 2 blog posts with full solution and sample code available for download:

Part 1:

[Saving many to many part 1](http://codenodes.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/saving-many-to-many-data-in-mvc4-and-ef-4-1-code-first-part-1/)

Part 2:

[Saving many to many part 2](http://codenodes.wordpress.com/2013/01/17/saving-many-to-many-data-in-mvc4-and-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2/)