# Populated list renders string of id's instead of checkboxes with MVC4 razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a form with some textfields to fill up the data of a project. On this form I would like to place all the possible categories from my database. I have created a viewmodel like shown in the answer of this question:

[Saving Many to Many relationship data on MVC Create view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531769/saving-many-to-many-relationship-data-on-mvc-create-view/11593957#11593957)

When i render my page all the ID's are shown instead of checkboxes for every element. Here is some of my code.

```
public ActionResult Metcat()
        {
            var projectCategoriesViewmodel = new ProjectCategory { Categories = PopulateCategories() };

            return View(projectCategoriesViewmodel);
        }

private ICollection<AssignedCategory> PopulateCategories()
        {
            var categories = Adapter.CategoryRepository.GetAll()

            var assignedCategories = new List<AssignedCategory>();
            foreach (var cat in categories)
            {
                assignedCategories.Add(new AssignedCategory
                {
                    CategoryID = cat.CategoryID,
                    CategoryName = cat.CategoryName,
                    Assigned = false
                });
            }
            return assignedCategories;
        }
```

CSHTML FILE

---

```
@model ProjectCategory
@using Freelauncher.Models

<h2>Metcat</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateProject", "Category", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>

        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Project.ProjectTitle)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Project.ProjectDescription-

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Categories)

    </fieldset>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>    
}
```

As you can see the viewModel is populated with all the categories
[image]

## The output

[image]

If needed more code or explanation I'll answer immediatly but I think all necessary information is available.

Comment: If you have an Editor Template for your `AssignedCategory` model, then that would be more useful to show than the current view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed the part about creating an editor template for the AssignedCategory:

```
@model YourNamespace.AssignedCategory

<fieldset>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CategoryID)    
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Assigned)
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CategoryName)
</fieldset>
```

This should be in `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/AssignedCategory.cshtml` or in `Views/SomeController/EditorTemplates/AssignedCategory.cshtml` if you don´t want it to be available for all controllers.

Then when your view does `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Categories)` it should call this template for each AssignedCategory

Comment: I already had the view but I managed to put the partial view in the Views/Shared folder... And ofcourse it didn't recognized it. Thx for the help