# ViewModel Object Convert to Entity Framework Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Goal: to save ViewModel object by Entity Framework. I have `UserViewModel` object which has list of `UnitViewModel`. Then, I have a `UserAdapter` class which converts `UserViewModel` into Entity Framework `User` object (see `Convert()`below how).

Now, my question is how do I convert this list of `UnitViewModel` to its corresponding Entity Framework `Unit` list? - Do I have to get each object from DB Context by calling something like `context.Units.Where(u=>myListofUnitIDs.Contains(u.UnitID))`?

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public Guid? UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreateTime { get; set; }
    public List<UnitViewModel> UserUnits { get; set; }
}


public class UnitViewModel
{
    public Guid UnitID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? SortIndex { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateTime { get; set; }
    public bool Assigned { get; set; }
}


public class UserAdapter
{
    public static User Convert(UserViewModel userView)
    {
        User user;
        if (userView.UserID.HasValue)
        {
            using (var provider = new CoinsDB.UsersProvider())
            {
                user = provider.GetUser(userView.UserID.Value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            user = new User();
        }

        user.FirstName = userView.FirstName;
        user.LastName = user.LastName;
        user.Password = StringHelper.GetSHA1(userView.Password);
        user.UserName = user.UserName;
        user.CreateTime = DateTime.Now;

        // Problem here :)
        // user.Units = userView.UserUnits;

        return user;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** The main concern here is that I have to retrieve each `Unit` from database to match (or map) it with `ViewModel.Unit` objects, right? Can I avoid it?

Comment: Perhaps AutoMapper may become handy in this case.

Comment: If you do not want unexpected behaviors, prevent using any Auto... things, and write plain code such as `userView.UserUnits.forEach(p=>user.Units.Add(new Unit{...}))`. It look ugly but work 100%

Comment: @GeneR, then I will have to get each `Unit` from database, right? Can I somehow avoid this?

Comment: `provider.GetUser()` may return user with all his units, then you can map it

Comment: Yes, but user may choose some new `Unit(s)` which do not exist in `user.Units` list

Answer (score 2):

For your information, this operation is called as *Mapping* mainly. So, you want to map your view model object to the entity object.

For this, you can either use already existed 3rd party library as [`AutoMapper`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwiD_rGsqdPJAhWBbhoKHX2QC_QQFggtMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nuget.org%2Fpackages%2FAutoMapper&usg=AFQjCNFI8zunKaCCH_n5MDw5L4uFzYEwUA&sig2=RNhpsaIZFt9SRi-oRdvyXg&cad=rja). It will map properties by reflection which have same name. Also you can add your custom logic with `After` method. But, this approach has some advantages and disadvantages. Being aware of these disadvantages could help you to decide whether you must use this API or not. So, I suggest you to read some articles about advantages and disadvantages of `AutoMapper` especially for converting entities to other models. One of such disadvantages is that it can be problem to change the name of one property in the view model in the future, and `AutoMapper` will not handle this anymore and you won't get any warning about this.

```
foreach(var item in userView.UserUnits)
{
     // get the mapped instance of UnitViewModel as Unit
     var userUnit = Mapper.Map<UnitViewModel, UserUnit>(item);
     user.Units.Add(userUnit);
}
```

***So, I recommend to write your custom mappers.*** 
For example, I have created a custom library for this and it maps objects lik this:

```
 user.Units = userView.UserUnits
       .Select(userUnitViewModel => userUnitViewModel.MapTo<UserUnit>())
       .ToList();
```

And I am implementing these mapping functions as:

```
 public class UserUnitMapper:
        IMapToNew<UnitViewModel, UserUnit>
    {
        public UnitViewModel Map(UserUnit source)
        {
            return new UnitViewModel
            {
                Name = source.Name,
                ...
            };
        }
    }
```

And then in runtime, I am detecting the types of the objects which will be used during mapping, and then call the `Map` method. In this way, your mappers will be seperated from your action methods. But, if you want it urgently, of course you can use this:

```
foreach(var item in userView.UserUnits)
{
     // get the mapped instance of UnitViewModel as Unit
     var userUnit= new UserUnit()
           {
               Name = item.Name,
               ...
           };

     user.Units.Add(userUnit);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can you review my update too? 
Also, I want to map it backwards Get `EF.Unit` from `ViewModel.Unit`. For this I'm afraid I will have to retrieve each `EF.Unit` from database. Can I somehow avoid this database retrieval?

Comment: @levi If you want to update then, you need original unit entities in context. Do you want to send update query based on new view models?

Comment: @levi If you don't need their original values somehow, then you can create new `Unit` objects and just set their Primary Key properties only.

Comment: Yes exactly, point is update `User` with all its `Units` and other properties of course

Comment: So, the update is happening in `Users` table and `UserUnits` table. The latter contains `UserID, UnitID` only. I do not want to update `Units` table itself, but only `UserUnits`

Comment: @levi Then, if  you don't want ti retrieve entities from database, you can make property ***modified*** manually. Like this:  `Entry(entity).Property("UnitID").IsModified = true;` And, EF will send update query for such properties.

Comment: @levi To tell the truth, the update in your question is about `Entity Framework`, I have answered in comment though. But, if you hace further more questions , then you can try to ask a new question. I mean try to split your questions, so you will get the answer without other explanations.

Comment: I tried to set `user.Units` = to `new Unit() {UnitID = "Existing Unit ID" }` but in this case EF tries to insert `Unit` objects together with `User` instead of inseting only `User` and inserting their relationship table.

Comment: @levi Firstly make entity state `Unchanged` and then `Entry(entity).Property("UnitID").IsModified = true;`

Comment: I gave only ids and then called `db.Units.Attach()` for each Unit.

Comment: @levi As I said change the state of the entity to `EntityState.Unchanged` and then make the property modified with the help of the code which I agve you above.